# Android Wear: How to notify smartphone via notifications

Tags: java, android, notifications, smartphone, sony-smartwatch

I'm currently trying to develop an android wear app and am trying to notify my smartphone when something happens via notifications. For example, when the smartwatch is counting my daily steps and notifies my smartphone on the steps count.

It can be a simple tutorial because I want to learn how to implement this.
On the Internet, I've found solutions which demonstrate smartphone notifying Smartwatch and not the other way.

Answer (score 0):

you can implement either notifications through google and for that you'll need a server code running in back end.

[see this ...](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/messages.html)

check the above link